# Registering Application Events in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5

i have a website made with *Laravel 4.2* and i want to upgrade to *Larave 5.x*. I tried upgrading and i can't seem to make it work completly. My problem is that i was using **App::before** and **App::after** events in *Laravel 4.2* (for setting some Cookies) and as i see they have been removed in *Laravel 5.x*. Am i missing something or i have to find a new way how to do this on the other way in *Laravel 5.x*? I tried placing the old code from filters.php to new filters.php and some other places but no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use middleware for this purpose instead.

1. Create your middleware.
2. Make it trigger before or after a page load by following the instructions under the "*Before / After* Middleware" header in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware
3. Add it to the global array in `app/Http/Kernel.php` - that's the one called `$middleware`